# Minimize SQL queries

Tags: php, sql, join

I have created a php code for listing the patients who have

1-email
2-zero future treatments
3-equal to or more than 1 finished treatments
4-latest finished treatment date is equal to 3 weeks ago from today

The problem is, I have more than 50K patients and for each patient, querying the above conditions taking a lot of time.

Is there a way of merging the sql queries into one, rather than for every patient having 3 or more queries which makes around 200k queries?

the code is below:

```
$today = date('Y-m-d');
$three_weeks_ago = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($today.'-3 weeks'));
$patients = $db->query("
SELECT 
    dg_patients_patients.id,
    dg_patients_patients.first_name,
    dg_patients_patients.last_name,
    dg_patients_patients.email,
    dg_clinics.clinic_name,
    dg_clinics.clinic_address,
    dg_clinics.clinic_phone 
FROM dg_patients_patients 
    LEFT JOIN dg_clinics ON dg_patients_patients.clinic_id = dg_clinics.id 
WHERE dg_patients_patients.email <> '' ORDER BY dg_patients_patients.first_name ASC ");

$now = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

foreach ($patients as $row){

    $patientID = $row['id'];

    //Get Patient Future Treatments
    $check_future_treatments = $db->column("SELECT id FROM dg_patient_treatment_finance WHERE treatment_type = :a1 AND patient_id = :a2 ",array("a1"=>"1","a2"=>"$patientID"));
    $future_treatments = count($check_future_treatments);

    //Get Patient Finished Treatments
    $check_finished_treatments = $db->column("SELECT id FROM dg_patient_treatment_finance WHERE treatment_type = :a1 AND patient_id = :a2 ",array("a1"=>"2","a2"=>"$patientID"));
    $finished_treatments = count($check_finished_treatments);


    if($future_treatments == 0 && $finished_treatments > 0 ) {

        $latest_finished_treatment_date = $db->single("SELECT plan_date FROM dg_patient_treatment_finance WHERE patient_id = :pid ORDER BY plan_date DESC LIMIT 1 ", array("pid"=>"$patientID"));

        if($latest_finished_treatment_date == $three_weeks_ago){

            echo $patientID.'- '.$row['first_name'].' '.$row['last_name'].' - '.$row['email'].'<br>';

        }
    }
```

Comment: Effectively your conditions 2,3 and 4 might mean the same as *latest treatment was 3 weeks ago*. At least from semantic point of view - I don't know how your `treatment_type` is handled. Can you apply this logic directly or sth disallows it?

Comment: If treatment_type is 1 that means future treatment, if it is 2 then it is finished treatment.

Comment: In db (row's) context "future treatment" is not determined by future date, but assigned type, so I can imagine `treatment_type=1` having `plan_date` last week or 3 weeks ago. At the moment your queries ignore that and count them as "future" thus eliminating such patient from the list. Don't know if its intentional (though semantically contradicting) or there's some hidden constraint that prevents having such rows in db.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to LEFT JOIN on dg_patient_treatment_finance, use a GROUP BY and use SUM in combination with the CASE statement.
And at the same time calculate the MAX plan_date.

```
SELECT 
    p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.email,
    c.clinic_name, c.clinic_address, c.clinic_phone,
    SUM(case when tf.treatment_type = 1 then 1 else 0 end) as total_treatment_type_1,
    SUM(case when tf.treatment_type = 2 then 1 else 0 end) as total_treatment_type_2,
    MAX(tf.plan_date) as max_plan_date
FROM dg_patients_patients p
LEFT JOIN dg_clinics c ON (p.clinic_id = c.id)
LEFT JOIN dg_patient_treatment_finance tf ON (p.id = tf.patient_id and tf.treatment_type IN (1,2))
WHERE p.email <> '' 
GROUP BY 
    p.id, p.first_name, p.last_name, p.email,
    c.clinic_name, c.clinic_address, c.clinic_phone
ORDER BY p.first_name, p.last_name
```

Then you can also simplify the calculation of $future_treatments and $finished_treatments by taking the content from the calculated sums.